# I would like to have my data to be percent yes/no as one bar per person using ggplot and dplyr

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, bar-chart, categorical-data

I can explain...

So essentially I would like to compare the percentage of yes recommendations to no recomendations for each reviewer. Unsure how to do this but I think a bar chart with the yes/no percentage stacked next to eachother for each reviewer compared to eachother would be ideal. I am having difficulty getting the percentages calculated as well as formulating the plot itself though I am close. Any alternatives would also be welcomed!

DATA

```
structure(list(Timestamp = structure(c(1542404919, 1542405223, 
1542405732, 1542406107, 1542406389, 1542406809, 1542407115, 1542407462, 
1542407858, 1542638598, 1542639521, 1542639522, 1542639536, 1542639885, 
1542640508, 1542640795, 1542641705, 1542642212, 1542705890, 1542706366
), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), Reviewer = c("Dan Wright", 
"A", "A", "A", "B", "D", 
"C", "C", "D", "D", "E", 
"B", "C", "D", "B", 
"E", "E", "E", "B", 
"A"), `Applicant Name:` = c("Mco", "Kai", 
"Shan", "Ken", "Clea", "Roha", 
"Ian", "Alex", "Kath", "Evan", 
"Jerr", "Beth", "Bria", "Hele", 
"Fred", "Sara", "Irma", "Alee", 
"Jerr", "Sara"), `Resume Score:` = c(4, 5, 5, 
3, 3, 5, 4, 4, 2, 4, 5, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4), `Cover Letter- Motivation Score:` = c(8, 
10, 7, 8, 9, 9, 7, 8, 8, 8, 9, 7, 6, 10, 5, 7, 7, 9, 5, 7), `Cover Letter- Strengths Score:` = c(7, 
8, 6, 7, 10, 7, 5, 7, 5, 6, 9, 5, 6, 10, 6, 4, 6, 8, 7, 8), `Cover Letter- Experiences Score:` = c(9, 
9, 8, 7, 8, 8, 8, 7, 8, 6, 9, 5, 5, 10, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 8), `Short Answer Question #1:` = c(7, 
8, 5, 8, 6, 5, 7, 6, 9, 7, 9, 8, 7, 10, 6, 9, 8, 8, 8, 8), `Short Answer Question #2:` = c(6, 
9, 9, 7, 6, 8, 6, 10, 9, 7, 7, 8, 4, 10, 6, 10, 7, 8, 8, 9), 
    `Short Answer Question #3:` = c(9, 6, 7, 10, 8, 5, 4, 7, 
    9, 6, 10, 1, 9, 10, 6, 10, 7, 9, 9, 9), Recomdendation = c("No", 
    "Yes", "No", "No", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "Yes", 
    "No", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
    "Yes"), `Are there any red flags for this candidate?` = c("None", 
    "None", "None", "None", "None", "Mentioned potential summer job that he feels would conflict with RA training dates", 
    "None", "None", "None", "none", "None", "None", "none", "None", 
    "none", "None", "none", "none", "none", "none")), row.names = c(NA, 
-20L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

CODE

```
library(readxl)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggthemes)


Apps <- read_excel("C:/Users/johnt/Desktop/Residential Education/RA Selection/Application Workbook.xlsx", 
                                   sheet = "Application Review")
View(Apps)

yayy <- Apps %>% 
  group_by(Reviewer, Recomdendation) %>% 
  summarize(counts = n())
###TURN ME INTO PERCENTS

ggplot(yayy,aes(x=Reviewer,y=Recomdendation,fill=factor(counts)))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity",position="dodge")+
  scale_fill_discrete(name="Gender",
                      breaks=c(1, 2),
                      labels=c("No", "Yes"))+
  xlab("Reviewer")+ylab("Percentage")+ theme_economist() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90))
```

In short, I would like to see what percentage of yes votes did each reviewer give and while this is the best way i could think of doing so I am open to new ideas!

EDIT:
Solved by @DiceBoyT ; Now I would like to make a column plot however it will not let me control my axises....

```
reviewers<- Apps %>% 
  group_by(Reviewer) %>% 
  summarise(percent_yes = mean(Recommendation == "Yes")) %>% 
  arrange(desc(percent_yes))
reviewers <-reviewers[-c(24), ]

ggplot(data = reviewers, mapping = aes(x = reorder(Reviewer, -percent_yes), y = percent_yes)) +
  geom_col(fill = "steelblue", color = "white")+
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(.5, 1)) +
  xlab("Reviewer")+ylab("Percentage") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly this should give you the data you need for your plot:

```
Apps %>% 
  group_by(Reviewer) %>% 
  summarise(percent_yes = mean(Recomdendation == "Yes"))   

#> # A tibble: 6 x 2
#>   Reviewer   percent_yes
#>   <chr>        <dbl>
#> 1 A            0.5  
#> 2 B            0.5  
#> 3 C            0.667
#> 4 D            1    
#> 5 Dan Wright   0    
#> 6 E            0.75
```

Comment: okay this is awesome! thank you so much; do you by chance know why this df will not allow me to control my y-axis change? See edit in post above!

Comment: If you want to change the y axis on a bar chart like this you need to do `coord_cartesian(ylim = c(.5, 1))` not `scale_y_continuous(limits=c(.5, 1))`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it using `facet_wrap` to split the plots by reviewer:

```
ggplot(Apps, aes(as.factor(Recomdendation))) +
  geom_bar(aes(y = (..count..)/sum(..count..))) +
  facet_wrap( ~ Reviewer) +
  labs(y = "Percentage")
```

Comment: It has to be on the dataframe "yayy"; additionally, It would be best to see them all together in one plot.